# Facebook feed with php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to share dynamic image with description on Facebook using PHP and Javascript. I have image.php which is generating image.

below code is generating image:

```
imagejpeg($jpg_image,$filename_result);
```

and javascript code for facebook calling is

```
 var obj = {
                method: 'feed',
                link: 'www.mysite.com',
                picture: 'image.php',
                name: 'Title',
                caption: 'Caption URL',
                description: 'Description'
            }; 

        FB.ui(obj, callback);
```

I want my image.php to return image to facebook dialog without creating file on server and calling like http..../myimage.jpg

Comment: Ok? What is your question?

Comment: @WizKid I'm not able to see image on Facebook dialog box which is generated from php page dynamically.

Comment: What is the full URL to the image?